# RDP session won't fill the screen when I drag it from my 17" monitor to my 22"

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, windows-8.1

I have a windows 8.1 PC setup with two monitors, my main monitor is 22" and the second a 17". I sometimes have Multiple RDP sessions open on my computer at once. Every time I open an RDP session it automatically opens on my 17" monitor, which is okay.

Whats annoying is if I drag the session over to my main (22") screen it won't go "full screen". When I drag it over to my bigger screen and hit "maximize" it will never fill the whole screen, it just stays the same size as it was on the smaller monitor.

Any ideas why it won't get bigger than the 17" screen even when on the bigger screen? (every other program I've used does)

Or something else that might work is if there was a way to make the session's "default" screen my main screen? I want to keep my bigger screen set as my main screen though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you establish a connection to a server, it sets the resolution of that session to what the client has. This prohibits you from changing the resolution when going to a different monitor, because technically it still has the same resolution on the remote side.

If you were to change the screen resolution on the remote side, the RDP session would then resize. Except that this is not allowed for terminal server sessions.

So what you want to do is start the RDP connection on the biggest screen. Note that if you move it to the smaller screen you will have scrollbars while windowed. By clicking on the icon in the upper left, and then from the menu select "Smart sizing", it will stretch the window and the scrollbar is gone.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me now considering the session is created from the server side and my 17" monitor doesn't have near the resolution. A question I have though is how do you change the "default" screen that an RDP session opens in?

Comment: @jayson Pretty sure it should just be a matter of dragging the RDP window over before you initiate the connection. You can also configure RDP to use both your monitors if you like - this works even with monitors of different sizes. I'm not sure what the "slim sizing" is that LPChip is referring to, but there is a way you can configure RDP to scale the image when the window resizes. This can make it distorted and hard to read though. It also requires manual editing of a config file IIRC.

Comment: If you open an RDP file, and it gives you a window before making the connection, you can drag this window to another monitor and then hit connect to make it conform that screen. Another option is editing the RDP file. This is kind of tricky however and your best option is to google for this to get all the details. (doesn't fit in a comment), but has been asked before.  As for the text, its called Smart sizing. I'm dutch, and the dutch translation for smart is slim. So I was having a brain fart there. sorry. X)

Comment: See also: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2013/12/16/resolution-and-scaling-level-updates-in-rdp-8-1.aspx

Comment: Because I had all of my server addresses "saved" so they automatically open, I didn't have the RDP prompt window to drag to the other screen. Now that I realize this, I believe I can just reset them all and they'll always open to the main screen instead. I also found the smart sizing feature which is quite nice. Appreciate it!

Comment: If you connect to a windows server 2012 environment, you can actually get it to change the resolution of the server side, so going full screen will always work. But I believe that is something that works by default. The blog I linked to mentions this though.

Comment: @LPChip is correct. Multi-monitor support (on the client side) has been vastly improved in 8.1 / 2012R2. In order to take advantage of this, you need that both the host and the client support RDP 8.1 (which means that the server is either 8.1 / 2012R2 and the client is Win7+ with latest Windows Updates installed).